# cannot work out why SDL2 streaming texture is black

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl, sdl-2

I am trying to draw individual pixels to an SDL2 streaming texture. I am attempting to store my pixels in a std::vector and then lock my texture, update the texture then unlock, pass it to the renderer and the present it.

However, I am always getting a black screen. I have tried several permutations of the below code but I am at a loss.

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include "Window.h"

Window::Window(unsigned int width, unsigned int height) :
    m_width(width), m_height(height)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO || SDL_INIT_TIMER) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL failed to initilize correct. Error: "
            << SDL_GetError << std::endl;
    }

    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Cotton Rasterizer - Hardeep Bahia 2021", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, m_width, m_height, 0);
    if (m_window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Window failed to initilize: " << SDL_GetError << std::endl;
    }

    m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE);
    if (m_renderer == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Renderer failed to initilize: " << SDL_GetError << std::endl;
    }

    m_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(m_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, m_width, m_height);
    if (m_texture == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to initilize: " << SDL_GetError << std::endl;
    }

    auto p_format = SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat(m_window);
    m_pixel_format = SDL_AllocFormat(p_format);
}

Window::~Window()
{
    SDL_FreeFormat(m_pixel_format);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(m_texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
}

void Window::test()
{
    SDL_Rect filledRect = { m_width / 4, m_height / 4, m_width / 2, m_height / 2 };
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(m_renderer, &filledRect);
}

void Window::present()
{
    SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);
}

void Window::clear()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_renderer, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 255.f);
    SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
}

void Window::draw(const std::vector<Pixel>& i_pixels)
{
    int pitch {(m_width * 4)};
    std::vector<Uint32> pixels(m_width * m_height * 4, 0);
    Uint32 color = SDL_MapRGBA(m_pixel_format, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    for (auto& a : i_pixels)
    {
        unsigned int offset = (m_width * 4 * a.m_position.y) + a.m_position.x * 4;
        pixels[offset + 0] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 1] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 2] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 3] = 255;
    }

    unsigned char* locked_pixels{};

    SDL_LockTexture(m_texture, NULL, reinterpret_cast<void **> (&locked_pixels) , &pitch);
    std::memcpy(locked_pixels, pixels.data(), pixels.size());
    SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture, NULL, pixels.data(), pitch);
    SDL_UnlockTexture(m_texture);
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, NULL);
}
```

My test function does draw, and is visible on the screen but it does not use the texture.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by changing the draw function to as follow:

```
    void Window::draw(const std::vector<Pixel>& i_pixels)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char>pixels(m_width * m_height * 4, 0);
    for (auto& i : i_pixels)
    {
        unsigned int x = i.m_position.x;
        unsigned int y = i.m_position.y;

        const unsigned int offset = (m_width * 4 * y) + (x * 4);

        pixels[offset] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 1] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 2] = 255;
        pixels[offset + 3] = 255;
    }

    unsigned char* lockedpixels = nullptr;
    int pitch = (m_width * 4);
    SDL_LockTexture(m_texture, NULL, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&lockedpixels), &pitch);
    std::memcpy(lockedpixels, pixels.data(), pixels.size());
    SDL_UpdateTexture(m_texture, NULL, pixels.data(), m_width * 4);
    SDL_UnlockTexture(m_texture);
    SDL_RenderCopy(m_renderer, m_texture, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: While you got it working, there are still some misconceptions. You don't need `SDL_UpdateTexture`; it even returns -1 indicating it can't update (because texture is locked). Pitch is returned from `LockTexture` as output parameter; you're supposed to use it, it is not a request "i want pitch to be that number". If you'll lock only a part of texture (rectangle somewhere in the middle) pitch could be very different from what you expect it to be. And finally you don't need your vector and memcpy, you can fill locked pixel data directly. That assumes you know pixel format, but so does memcpy too.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I'm finding SDL2.0 documentation very vague. So I appreciate you clarifying it for me.